# Splicing names in a list, and adding characters to a specific string?

Tags: r, list, rename, tail

Hello there: I currently have a list of file names (100s) which are separated by multiple "/" at certain points. I would like to find the last "/" in each name and replace it with "/Old". A quick example of what I have tried:

I have managed to do it for a single file name in the list but can't seem to apply it to the whole list.

```
Test<- "Cars/sedan/Camry"
```

Then I know I tried finding the last "/" in the name I tried the following :

```
Last <- tail(gregexpr("/", Test)[[1]], n= 1)
str_sub(Test, Last, Last)<- "/Old"
```

Which gives me

```
Test[1] "Cars/sedan/OldCamry"
```

Which is exactly what I need but I am having troubling applying `tail` and `gregexpr` to my list of names so that it does it all at the same time.

Thanks for any help!

Apologies for my poor formatting still adjusting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file names are in a character vector you can use `str_replace()` from the `stringr` package for this:

```
items <- c(
  "Cars/sedan/Camry",
  "Cars/sedan/XJ8",
  "Cars/SUV/Cayenne"
)

stringr::str_replace(items, pattern = "([^/]+$)", replacement = "Old\\1")
[1] "Cars/sedan/OldCamry" "Cars/sedan/OldXJ8"   "Cars/SUV/OldCayenne"
```

Comment: Would this work if I have some cases of more than 2 "/" in the name? For example : "cars/sedan/toyota/Camry". Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, it should. The regular expression in `str_replace()` is saying that it should extract the last word of the string after the last forward slash.

Comment: IT WORKED perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool. Please be sure to mark whichever response you think best suits you as the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a **stringi** function as an alternative.

If your dataframe is "df" and your text is in column named "text.

```
library(stringi)
    df %>% 
      mutate(new_text=stringi::stri_replace_last_fixed(text, '/', '/Old '))
```